# how to get all approved version of SharePoint list item using jsom or REST API's in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, version-history, content-approval

Is there any way to get only all approved version no of list item

[image]
I have tried the JSOM and SP Services but in both I am getting all the version no
I referring  the  [blog](http://techfindings-prem.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-get-all-versions-of-list-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

OData__ModerationStatus is the item property that corresponds to approval. If you get the list item from the SharePoint REST API then you can parse the response for approval status.

0 = Approved, 1 = Rejected, 2 = Pending, 3 = Draft

Comment: But i want to get all **approved version** number of single item

Comment: This will get all versions of a single list item GET /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/versions/ , then you just need to filter where OData_ModerationStatus = 0